# Java find value in a string using regex

Tags: java, regex, java-8

I'm wondering about the behavior of using the `matcher` in java.

I have a pattern which I compiled and when running through the results of the matcher i don't understand why a specific value is missing.

My code:

```
String str = "star wars";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("star war|Star War|Starwars|star wars|star wars|pirates of the caribbean|long strage trip|drone|snatched (2017)");
Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("\nRegex : " matcher.group());
    }
```

I get hit with "star war" which is right as it is in my pattern.

But I don't get "star wars" as a hit and I don't understand why as it is part of my pattern.

Comment: The first alternative in the alternation group that matches "wins", and the rest is not checked. Once the `star war` is matched, the text is consumed, there won't be any more passes. It is expected. What behavior do you need?

Comment: Is there a way to return all hits?

Comment: You would have to check each pattern against the string separately instead of as a long chain of alternations.

Comment: Understood.. thanks guys

Comment: See http://ideone.com/gGcALb. BTW, you have 2 "star wars" :)

Comment: @omri_saadon - don't neglect to escape the parentheses in the regex -- "(2017)" should be "\\\(2017\\\)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior is expected because [**alternation**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in NFA regex is "eager", i.e. the first match wins, and the rest of the alternatives are not even tested against. Also, note that once a regex engine finds a match in a consuming pattern (and yours is a consuming pattern, it is not a zero-width assertion like a lookahead/lookbehind/word boundary/anchor) the index is advanced to the end of the match and the next match is searched for from that position.

So, once your first `star war` alternative branch matches, there is no way to match `star wars` as the regex index is before the last `s`.

Just check if the string contains the strings you check against, the simplest approach is with a loop:

```
String str = "star wars";
String[] arr = {"star war","Star War","Starwars","star wars","pirates of the caribbean","long strage trip","drone","snatched (2017)"};
for(String s: arr){
    if(str.contains(s))
        System.out.println(s);
}
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/vCIw7r)

By the way, your regex contains `snatched (2017)`, and it does not match `(` and `)`, it only matches `snatched 2017`. To match literal parentheses, the `(` and `)` must be escaped. I also removed a dupe entry for `star wars`.

Comment: This approach is better, but then we should also split the string on `|` and match `str` entirely in order to avoid problem with movies like `AI` or so.

Comment: @steffen: I split with `\|` just to quickly build an array. I think the best way is to define it as usual, with `String[] arr = {"term1", "term2", "etc."};`. Note I did not even remove dupes, I guess those are served at design time.

Comment: I decided to edit the answer to show how the array of search terms should be defined. Splitting with `"\\|"` is hacky.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to build your regex would be like this:

```
String pattern = "[Ss]tar[\\s]{0,1}[Ww]ar[s]{0,1}";
```

Breaking down:

- **[Ss]**: it will match either S or s in the first position
- **\s**: representation of space
- **{0,1}**: the previous character (or set) will be matched from 0 to 1 times

An alternative is:

```
String pattern = "[Ss]tar[\\s]?[Ww]ar[s]?";
```

- **?**: the previous character (or set) will be matched once or not at all

For more information, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Edit 1: fixed typo (`\s` -> `\\s`). Thanks, @eugene.

Comment: `[\s]{0,1}` should really be `\\s+` there could be many spaces probably

Comment: Eugene: * would cause to match 0 or more times. By using {0,1} it says to match 0 or 1 times only.

Comment: @Eugene - '\\s*' would allow things like 'star       wars' to match, as well.

Comment: @marklark, yeah, I know that. I just wanted to point out a better way to build Regex'es than the one on the question. In fact, that is the first line of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match the whole input sequence, so you should use [`Matcher.matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) or add `^` and `$`:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(star war|Star War|Starwars|star wars|"
        + "star wars|pirates of the caribbean)$");
```

will print

```
Regex : star wars
```

But I agree with @NAMS: Don't build your regex like this.